# Scala usage statistics

Tags: scala, usage-statistics

We are a small team of developers and are currently in the process of drafting a business idea targeting scala developers as potential customers. In order to convince investors we obviously need some numbers on usage, some of which we were unable to find:

- While there is a list of companies listed at [typesafe.com](http://www.typesafe.com) we were not able to find out what they actually do with Scala and what the total market share of Scala is.
- The [TIOBE Index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) lists scala as the 29th most popular (?) language but the methods seem questionable and it seems hard to find out what that means for the real world. Are there any surveys where developers were actually asked what they use, which involve less guessing? (Possibly even in a commercial context)
- For us it would be great to be able to print some (preferably exponential) curves on the development of Scala usage in the last years. While that is how we feel that scala is spreading we dont have anything to proove it.
- Is there any evidence on scala beeing popular in the financial sector or other specific areas? For example, there seems to be some kind of a "Scala hotspot" in the financial district of London and it would be great to proove that.

Any hints on citeable surveys and studies would be awesome!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'd say that this is not the appropriate place to ask for information on language adoption. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for a clear explanation.

Comment: You could also use look at the number of open positions for Scala developers on sites like monster.com or stepstone.com. Or look at how many people on sites like linkedin.com list Scala as one of their programming languages.

Comment: += [functionaljobs](http://functionaljobs.com) to the list of scala job postings. I know, it won't get good comparison on say java vs scala, but you may have a good feeling on number of scala jobs against other fp languages (clojure, erlang, haskell, ...)

Answer (score 3):

this won't tell you how many people are using it, but is a good indicator of trending technologies, as oposed to TIOBE, which rates any tech invented since the wheel

RedMonk uses [github + stackoverflow](http://redmonk.com/sogrady/2013/02/28/language-rankings-1-13/)

Scala is indeed popular in Finance in London. We are using it for our projects in a Front Office department in a major investment bank.